# OGR2OGR convert linestring to multilinestring

Tags: ogr2ogr, linestring

I have a shapefile with 3D linestrings. I want to convert this to 2D multilinestrings

I tried:-

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326  Road_wgs84_2d_mlt.shp Road_wgs84.shp -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -dim 2 -progress
```

But this:-

```
ogrinfo -so -al Road_wgs84_2d_mlt.shp
```

Gives me:-

```
OGRFeature(Road_wgs84_2d_mlt1):0
  ID (String) = D291A5DD-66FA-4764-87F9-80D9FB8A83F5
  DISTNAME (String) = (null)
  ROADNUMBER (String) = B9097
  CLASSIFICA (String) = B Road
  DRAWLEVEL (String) = 0
  OVERRIDE (String) = F
  FEATCODE (Integer) = 15743
  LINESTRING (-3.444786910479451 56.164060208744381   52.480434944853187,-3.446986978754905 56.164483742630381 52.48251925688237)
```

As you can see the -nlt flag has not promoted the linestring to multilinestring. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried -nlt MULTILINESTRING with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefile driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html has own layer creation option SHPT=type for setting the geometrytype. Shapefiles do not make difference between linestrings and multilinestrings, nor between polygons and multipolygons. What you can do is to drop the Z coordinate by defining the corresponding 2D shapetype:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326  Road_wgs84_2d_mlt.shp Road_wgs84.shp -lco SHPT=ARC -progress
```